# (re)naming only certain column names based on index, pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been looking everywhere but couldn't figure out how to name columns on index. For example, how can I name only the first 3 columns of a dataframe that has no header so that they each have a name (e.g. A,B,C) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataFrame method `rename` takes as an input a dictionary of values to rename. A dataframe with no headers has its columns named by integers, so for your example you would use the dictionary `{0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C'}`:

```
In [1]: pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2,3]])
Out[1]:
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  2  3

In [2]: pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2,3]]).rename(columns = {0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C'})
Out[2]:
   A  B  C  3
0  0  1  2  3
```

If you want a solution that works for an arbitrary list of labels, and column names, you can create your dictionary using a `zip`:

```
L = ['A','B','C']
df.rename(columns = dict(zip(df.columns[:len(L)], L)))
Out[3]:
   A  B  C  3
0  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using .rename, but forgot to use actual numbers instead of strings e.g. '1' :(.